# How can I debug a C# COM assembly when it's being called from a native win32 application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, delphi, com

I'm developing a C# assembly which is to be called via COM from a Delphi 7 (iow, native win32, not .net) application.

So far, it seems to work. I've exported a TLB file, imported that into my Delphi project, and I can create my C# object and call its functions.

So that's great, but soon I'm going to **really** want to use Visual Studio to debug the C# code while it's running. Set breakpoints, step through code, all that stuff.

I've tried breaking in the Delphi code after the COM object is created, then looking for a process for VS to attach to, but I can't find one.

Is there a way to set VS2008 up to do this? I'd prefer to just be able to hit f5 and have VS start the Delphi executable, wait for the C# code to be called, and then attach itself to it.. But I could live with manually attaching to a process, I suppose.

Just please don't tell me I have to make do with MessageBox.Show etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the VS2008 project properties page, on the Debug tab, there's an option to set a different Start Action.

This can be used to run an external program (e.g. your Delphi app) when you press F5.

Comment: It is pretty handy.  I discovered it when writing a C# assembly which was being called from Excel.

Answer (score 10):

Place the following in the method you wish to debug:

```
#if DEBUG
    if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        Debugger.Launch();
#endif
```

When you want to debug, build a debug version and use that in your application.  When this code runs, a dialog pops up asking if you want to attach a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You can just attach to the native application and see breakpoint, view stacks, watches etc. normally.  You'll need to attach after the COM object is created.

I put a Afx MsgBox when the object is created to stop the application's flow and then attach the debugger.